# Adding command line string to array as separate characters

Tags: c

What I am trying to do is add a command line argument into an array as indvidual characters.
So when the user runs the program `./program bacon` "bacon" is stored in an array as

```
array k[]= {'b', 'a', 'c', 'o', 'n'};
```

I hope I explained it well enough I am new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I understand you're new to programming, but surely this looks familiar, no?

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  // ...
}
```

`char **argv` is a pointer to a char pointer, but for your purposes, you can consider it to be the equivalent of `char *argv[]`. The difference is subtle, but worth noting, since this caveat is vital to understanding the way strings work in C. `char *argv[]` is explicitly typed as an array of char pointers, while `char **argv` could be an array but you wouldn't know until you try to access it as such. Given that it's your main function, it's safe to assume this will always be instantiated appropriately.

Anyway, moving past the tangent, we have an array of null-terminated strings in `char **argv` in our main function. From your question, I can see a simple path we should follow. I will assume that only one argument is expected (you should otherwise be capable of implementing cases which deal with different circumstances).

1. Get the length of the first argument (`argv[1]`) passed to our program.
2. Populate the array with characters from the `argv[1]`.
3. Print out our array so we know it works.

In our `main` function, we store the length of `argv[1]` to `n`, and declare our array of size `n`. We then iterate through the first string, character-by-character, and store each character into the next open slot of our array. At the end, we repeat our loop and print out each item of our array so we can verify it works.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int n = strlen(argv[1]);
  char arr[n];

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    arr[i] = argv[1][i];

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%c ", arr[i]);

  printf("\n");
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks this helped me understand exactly what was going on I got it working!

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, "bacon" will be passed to you through argv[1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strcpy.html) which is a `char *` and a null terminated string. Now your array which you want to create should also be a char array.

Logically you should just be copying the input (argv[1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strcpy.html)) into the new array.

You can use string manipulation functions like [strcpy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strcpy.html) or [strncpy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strncpy.html)

**Note:** I am not directly adding the code in this solution as it will be better for you to try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use arguments passed to main. You will already get an array argv[1] which does this for you. I think it's best you read some articles like this one to get started - http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter10/arguments_to_main.html